# Pronunciation on "ll" for in the sentence "me llamo"

Tags: pronunciación

How do you pronounce the consonants "ll"?? I want to say my name in Spanish but I keep saying "ll" like how Americans say in English.Then people say that I am wrong but don't tell me how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pronounce it as a `y` in English. So you would pronounce it

> Me yamo [your name]

examples:

> **Yamas**
>
> Como te **yamas**

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it works. Would definitely work in Spain, but might be more complicated than that if you want to achieve a perfect pronunciation for a given country. See [this related question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3/5481) and its answers