# Regional pronunciation of "ll": [j] vs [ʎ]

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronunciación, yeísmo

I'm well aware that *ll* may be pronounced differently according to regions. We already have [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3/12) on the most common pronunciations of [j] and [ʒ].  But I've come across a couple examples on [forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com/) that sound to me like a [ʎ].  The profile of the [Alius92](http://forvo.com/user/Alius92/), the speaker in question  says he's in Mexico City.

[Many of his contributed words](http://forvo.com/user/Alius92/) feature the *ll*, and many include what sounds to me like the [ʎ] pronunciation.

Examples:

- [camello](http://forvo.com/word/camello/#es)
- [caudillo](http://forvo.com/word/caudillo/)
- [Maillín](http://forvo.com/word/maill%C3%ADn/)

Is this an accepted pronunciation?  Is this just an odd speaker?  Or perhaps his recording equipment is just bad?

If this is a common pronunciation, where is it typically found?  Many months in Mexico DF tell me it's *not* common there, despite this speaker's profile on forvo!  Is there a name for this pronunciation variation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That isn't [ʎ] but a hypercorrective [lj], often used by *yeístas* when trying to imitate non-*yeísta* pronunciation, such that I hear *camelio*, *caudilio*, etc. Mexico is fully *yeísta*, so such a pronunciation (or even as [ʎ]) can be generally assumed to be affected speech.

Speakers who distinguish *ll* [ʎ] from *y* (in its diverse regional pronunciations) didn't traditionally have a name, as that was the standard pronunciation. But now that most people are *yeísta*, the term *lleísta* has come to be used.

Comment: Recuerdo que en el doblaje (en español americano) del oso Yogui el narrador decía "chiquilios".

Answer (score 2):

I think he's an odd speaker. I'm a native speaker and I live near DF. I also hear [ʎ]. I'm not even able to say that words like Alius92. His profile says that his from mexico but [his pronunciation of detallazos](http://es.forvo.com/word/detallazos/) is like pronunciation from spain using [θ] instead of [s]. So I definitely think it is not a common pronunciation in Mexico, and maybe, nor spanish speakers in general.

Comment: I agree. That guy sounds weird. He is anything but mexican.