# "suavecillo" or "suavecito"?

Tags: significado, letras-de-canciones, diminutivos

For the song *Eres para mí* by Julieta Venegas, I'm finding conflicting lyrics on the web.

For one line in the song, I'm finding two versions:

> El viento me lo dijo con un soplo **suavecito**
>
> El viento me lo dijo con un soplo **suavecillo**

From reading the lips of the artist that sings this lyric (in the music video), it appears she's saying *suavecillo*.

However, I'm not finding anywhere on the web translations for either *suavecito* or *suavecillo*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed quite complicated to distinguish whether Julieta Venegas says *suavecito* or *suavecillo*. I listened to the verse few times and I still cannot tell.

However, the diminutive for *suave* cannot be <strike>***suavecillo***</strike>. Instead, use ***suavecito***. You cannot find this in the normal dictionary, since diminutives and superlatives normally are not listed there (its size would increase dramatically!).

Luckily, for this specific case we have [RAE saying this in Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/563498688891600896):

> #RAEconsultas Como diminutivo de «suave» existen «suavecito» y «suavito». El superlativo es «suavísimo».

Comment: My Google search skills are lacking! How did you find this!? Thank you so much!

Comment: I checked "diminutivo de suave" : ) I was biased because I already knew _suavecillo_ is not correct, so the browsing through the result was faster (being a native speaker always helps haha)

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson I always use _suavito_ when telling my son that he must pet our cats in a soft, tender way, rather than almost hitting them: _"¡Guille, suaviiiiiiito!"_

Comment: There are some caribbean countries where they use the ending -illo and even -ico to form a diminutive. Although the RAE says it is not correct, I believe it is in those countries.

Comment: A mi 'suavecillo' no me sonaba nada mal y estaba a punto de expresarlo cuando vi el enlace que publica @456L el cual en mi opinión confirma esta respuesta. Otra cosa que aprendí.

Comment: Note that the RAE didn't say that the *suavecillo* is wrong. *-ito* is the standard diminutive ending, and some words require infixes like *-ec-*, others reject them, and others, like *suave* go with or without them. That doesn't make *suavecillo*, *suavín*, *suaveciño*, or even *suavingo* wrong, just far less common and restricted to particular dialects.

Comment: @guifa yep, as discussed in Hithere's answer, I made it too categorical. However, since it is the RAE telling, I would not use _suavecillo_ in a kind-of-formal context, while _suavecito_ could. That is, _suavecito_ seems to be more widespread and standard.

Answer (score 10):

Contrary to what fedorqui states in [his answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17494/1674), you can rarely talk in binary terms (correct/incorrect) when addressing language use or, specially, dictionaries. Dictionaries' task is to exclusively establish which uses are the most common in any given language and describing them, not prescribing them.

Anyhow, the use of the diminutive suffix *-illo* (as in *suavecillo*)/*-illa* is actually widespread in Meridional Spanish as well as in other transitional dialects. The suffix *-ico*/*-ica* is also used in other regions of the country such as Jaén and Murcia. In addition to that, *-ino*/*-ina* is widespread in Asturias, *-uco*/*-uca* in Cantabria, etc. We have a pretty diverse language dialect-wise. We sometimes even use diminutives of diminutives: *chiquitito*, *poquinina*.

[A source from Wikibooks ("Otros sufijos diminutivos")](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol/Morfolog%C3%ADa/Los_diminutivos).

Comment: Muy buen enlace. Ahí dice como crear el diminutivo con -ito (suavito) y como se crean los diminutivos de palabras terminadas en 'e' (suavecito). Concluyo que cuando @fedorqui habla en binario es correcto entonces. +1

Comment: Interesting approach. I agree I was too categorical: something that is not used today can end up being part of the vocabulary in few years.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion arises because we never hear the end of the word, as it overlaps with the next line, that starts with:

> Y yo...

So we hear something like:

> suaveci-- Y yo

In many Spanish speaking regions including Mexico, *Y yo* sounds exactly as *-illo*. That's why one could hear this as *suavecillo*. See this [question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-to-pronounce-the-consonants-y-and-ll) and this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo)

In the [release version](https://youtu.be/pj2ntDiXJCk?t=126) (2:06) of the song, [Anita Tijoux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ana_Tijoux) sings the *El viento...* line, and Julieta Venegas the following one. But when singing live you can hear Venegas recreating this overlapping effect by herself. Like [here](https://youtu.be/84jgq3zofPE?t=140) (2:20), [here](https://youtu.be/YJ_hcpwbT9A?t=140) (2:20), and [here](https://youtu.be/R_nSkhWwvdU?t=153) (2:33).

If she could finish pronouncing the word she would certainly say ***suavecito***, as she does in [her song with that exact title](https://youtu.be/7_g3XisJWaw?t=41) (0:41) :)

As the other answers explained, *suavecito* is the standard [diminutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) for *suave* (*soft*). It can be understood as even softer than just *soft*.

As Hithere's answer said, the diminutive can also be form with *-illo* in some regions, which together with the overlapping effect may have led some people to think *suavecillo* was what's said in the song.

Comment: This is a good work you have made!

Comment: You are implying that *yo* and *llo* have the same sound. They are different when spoken I think.

Comment: @Ustanak as I say, it depends on the region. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo

Comment: @Ustanak updated the answer with links

Answer (score 1):

The songs says: Suavecito.

"Suavecillo" its a regular expression used on the north of the country (México).

The finish on words "illo" its so normal. "Plebillo" (Plebito), "Perrillo" (Perrito), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Suavecillo is more vernacular, but almost not used in Mexico.

Julieta would certainly say "suavecito".

Suavecillo would be more Venezuelan.