# Pronounce and distinguish "ñi" and "ni"?

Tags: pronunciación

I'm new to Spanish and I'm trying to learn pronunciation first.

I listened to a few materials and I'm finding it difficult to distinguish "ñi" and "ni", <s>for example "niñito"</s>. And it's even harder to immitate that. So how should I go ahead?

I found another pair of examples: ***compañía*** and ***compaña***

Comment: Should we assume that English is your native language? Otherwise there may be similar sounds in your language, e.g. gn in French.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Actually no but you can assume so. I'm native to Chinese but English is almost "native".

Comment: I agree with @pablodf76's answer. I would only add that if you require some sort of visual cue to help with the pronunciation, for example, with *niñito*, you might think to separate the word as "nin" and "yito" as if the word were "nin'yito", and work on bridging the pronunciation gap little by little, until the point where you can see "niñito" and not have to think twice about it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first thing would be to note that *ni* + vowel and *ñ* do not sound that different (which is the point of your question, obviously), so in many cases you won't need to imitate it perfectly. That is, *nieto* and **ñeto* (the latter word does not exist) would be very difficult to distinguish in practice even for native speakers, unless pronounced slowly. In a word with *n* next to *ñ* such as *niñito*, however, the contrast becomes readily apparent.

What you need to understand is how *n* and *ñ* are produced.

Spanish *n* (IPA: /n/) is **alveolar** (when followed by a vowel), as in English. The tip of the tongue must be placed flat against the alveoli, which are the spaces just behind the roots of your upper front teeth.

Spanish *ñ* (IPA: /ɲ/) is **palatal**: the middle of the tongue must be raised and pressed against the hard palate, while the tip will be probably lowered and pressed against the back of your lower teeth.

There are a ton of resources on the web for this, but check out [this one](http://clas.mq.edu.au/speech/phonetics/phonetics/consonants/nasal_stops.html), which has drawings.

You might want to use *niñito* as a test. If you pronounce it OK, you will notice how the tongue shifts in your mouth, the tip first striking your alveoli and then coming down to touch your lower teeth. If instead you're pronouncing **ninito*, your tongue will tap your alveoli twice in succession.

ADDED: This applies also to the difference between *ll* and *li*, but as explained in this answer [about the pronunciation of *ll*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-to-pronounce-the-consonants-y-and-ll/410#410), in most Spanish dialects *ll* has merged with *y* and the merged phoneme is pronounced generally rather differently and it's not as prone to confusion with *li*.

Comment: Does the same apply to "lli" and "li"?

Comment: "niñi" -> "ni nyi" :: "lilli" -> "li [l]yi"

Comment: About *lli* and *li*: well yes and no. Check out [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/410/14627). I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Minimal pairs: *unir* (to unite) / *uñir* (to join animals on a team by a yoke). Also: *montañismo* (mountaineering) / *Montanismo* (Montanism, an early Christian movement); *canilla* (shinbone; thin leg) / *cañilla* (diminutive of caña "reed, cane")

Comment: So close are /nj/ and /ɲ/ that sometimes the *ñ* is used to replace *ni* in (primarily to represent /nji/.  For example, if someone's name is *Antonia*, then to add *-ita*, neither *Antonita* nor *Antoniita* are right.  Instead, it's *Antoñita*.

Comment: I guess for me while learning to read and write it was a surprise to find that it was *compañía* not *companía* (the latter is how most people actually pronounce it).

Comment: I heard that `ll` has a sound similar to the "s" in "mea**s**ure", or English IPA `ʒ`. Is it?

Comment: @iBug It depends. See the link "about the pronunciation of ll" in my answer, and check Wikipedia: *[yeísmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo)*.

Comment: A few other examples - [*pergenio*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SbcV52n) being an alternate spelling for [pergeño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sbko5iD); similarly [*buganvilia*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6FYmiJX)/[*buganvilla*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6FZQA5X), [*enjullo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FTCmRjG)/[*enjulio*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FTCQ30T)