# Any variety with the palatal glide [j] in words like cuello?

Tags: pronunciación, dialectos, fonología

Some friends of mine insist that in some varieties of Spanish, words like *cuello* and *yo* have the palatal glide [j] in them. However, I've only ever found the palatal lateral liquid [ʎ] or the palatal voiced fricative [ʝ] in transcriptions of these sort of words. Are there any varieties of Spanish where the palatal glide [j] is actually used?

Comment: I believe there is indeed a palatal glide, but it is an allophone of [ʝ]. For example, [j] is heard very frequently in all types of dialects (except maybe el rioplatense, other than where it is part of a diphthong), but if somebody were asked to enunciate or to repeat themselves, they would most likely pronounce it [ʝ] (or even [dʒ]).

Answer (score 2):

The pronunciation of the word **yo** by people from Santiago del Estero, a province  in northern Argentina may sound as what I understand the palatal glide sound is. I am basing my recomendation on  [this video](https://youtu.be/dfoRdKuPF9I), in which at minute 4:38 the glide sound is presented (as `produced with very little constriccion of flow, so little in fact that they are often refered as sunny vowels [j] )`

Hear an artist  (from that region) pronouncing that  peculiar way as it is common there. The portion that matters starts at sec 19 and ends at sec 25, where he says

> (...) muchas gracias. Ustedes saben que yo [***io***] vengo desde Quimili a entregarles una sonrisa (...)

Comment: Hi.  I'd like to copyedit this part: "may sound as what I understand that the palatal glide sound appears" but I'm not sure exactly what you meant.  Can you explain it another way, or in Spanish?

Comment: I slightly corrected using "may sound as what I understand the palatal glide sound is" Does that come more clear?

Comment: @ipp Isn't this sunny vocalization of the OP's liquid lambda called _yeísmo_? It's common in Chile, too.

Comment: Like this: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31524/24536

Comment: It looks like you meant to link to a video of an artist from Santiago del Estero speaking?

Answer (score -2):

As a general matter and not to cover every single instance of this phenomenon, the following is true.

palatal glide:

> In linguistics, a "palatal glide" is the term for the speech sound
> represented **by the letter "y" in the English alphabet, and the letter
> [j] in the phonetic transcription**. A palatal glide is produced by
> holding the tongue high in the mouth, forcing air along the palate.
> Palatal glides are found, for example, in the first syllable of "yes"
> and the last syllable of "boy."

[palatal glide](https://everything2.com/title/palatal+glide)

[yeísmo in the RAE's Panhispanico de dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/ye%C3%ADsmo)

> yeísmo. Consiste en pronunciar como **/y/**, en sus distintas variedades
> regionales, **el dígrafo ll (→ ll)**: **[kabáyo] por caballo**, [yéno] por
> lleno. El yeísmo está extendido en amplias zonas de España y de
> América y, aunque quedan aún lugares en que pervive la distinción en
> la pronunciación de ll e y, es prácticamente general entre los
> jóvenes, incluso entre los de regiones tradicionalmente
> distinguidoras. Su presencia en amplias zonas, así como su creciente
> expansión, hacen del yeísmo un fenómeno aceptado en la norma culta.

[Bolding mine]

Of course. One of the first things an intermediate or advanced Spanish class teacher will point out that the ll sound in most regions of Spain is like a y (a palatal glide in English) and in Argentina (Rio Plate region), Uruguay and parts of Chile, it's like a j or sh sound (depending on how you describe it using the regular alphabet),

**In parts of Argentina, Uruguay, and parts of Chile, the "ll" sound which is usually pronounced like a "y", sounds more like a "j" or "sh".**

So, **cuello** (with the [j], or y sound] becomes cu-eh-joe, that is: cuesho (with the /ʃ/ sound).

- **caballo** becomes cabajoe or cabasho.

This is informally referred to in English when describing this pronunciation as shushing.

The linguistic writing for this is: /ʃ/ (sh).

In sum, the ll or [j] becomes sh/j or /ʃ/.

[How Spanish is pronounced in regions](https://www.superprof.co.uk/blog/how-spanish-is-pronounced-regions/)

Comment: downvoters": tsk, tsk, tsk

Comment: downvote again. Again tsk, tsk, tsk. My answer is correct.